# "for a whole week" vs "for the whole week"

Tags: articles

which of these two sentences is correct?

> 1. It has been snowing **for a whole week** already.
> 2. It has been snowing **for the whole week** already.

Comment: They're both valid, anmd in many contexts are interchangeable. Sometimes (for example, a future reference where no *particular* week is contextually identifiable, such as *Before I die my ambition is to stay at the Hilton for **a** whole week"*) you'd probably be more likely to use the indefinite article. And vice-versa - *"He arrived yesterday, and expects to stay for **the** whole week"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I wonder should the week with **the** be ongoing (or due shorty to start), or is it okay to use *the whole week* for a week that lies in a more distant future (or past).

Comment: @CopperKettle: The issue of when weeks start and end is a minefield in itself! On reflection, I guess that for some speakers *on some days of the week* my second example above could imply he expects to stay for 6 or 8 days (perhaps even 5 or 9) rather than exactly 7. But if it had been ***a** week* that would almost always mean exactly 7 days (since there's no "competing" contextual week to be potentially referenced by the definite article). But that doesn't imply ***the*** can't be used for "non-current" weeks - just that one tends to use ***a*** more often in such contexts.

Comment: Would you say 'It has been raining for the whole hour'? If so, do you think context is required?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["a" vs "the" to introduce a company](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/87370/a-vs-the-to-introduce-a-company)

Answer (score 2):

'The whole week' refers to a specific week e.g. I'm going to Jackson on the 7th for work, I'll be gone to whole week so don't wait for me'. Whereas 'a whole week' refers to any whole week e.g. 'Building a good barn usually takes them a whole week'.