# "a" vs "the" to introduce a company

Tags: articles

I want to write a company introduction page (or About page) in my website, and start the sentence like the following:

> SelfCompany is a company that makes your life better by XXXing...
>
> SelfCompany is the company that makes your life better by XXXing...

However, between the two sentences above, I don't get which article to use.

I know that in general, you use `a` to talk about what a listener doesn't know yet, or an object that is not stated yet. (BTW is `a listener` correct here or is `the listener` or `listeners` better?)

However, I'm sure that my users already know it is *my company* to talk about, and he or she wants to know what kind of a company it is.

So which article is the best? Are both correct or is only the one correct?

Comment: Your first version (with indefinite article ***a***) implies Selfcompany is just *one of many* companies that make life better. Using the *definite* article ***the*** implies Selfcompany is ***the only one*** that does this. This difference arises from the "standard" principle that ***the*** references ***a specific thing*** known to both speaker and audience and/or previously mentioned in the current conversation.

Comment: See [Are there any simple rules for choosing the definite vs. indefinite (vs. none) article?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, If you posted your comment as an answer, it would be perfect.

Comment: @Mark Hubbard: I'd be *very* surprised if this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: While looking for ELL duplicates, which like @FumbleFingers I'm fairly certain exist, I came across this http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/7698/ which might be relevant if not a duplicate.

Comment: Well, if the question is about when to use `a` vs `the`, I'm pretty certain it is a duplicate. But I wanted to ask a little more specific question in introducing a/the company.

Comment: @ColleenV: Good catch! It seems to me this *is* a duplicate, because it turns on *the "standard" principle that **the** references **a specific thing*** in the case of *the/a company* just the same as *the/an average person* (where ***a*** implies the existence of *other* companies/people of the type being referenced). But I already *understand* this principle (after all, it's *my* answer on the "original"), and perhaps I'm wrong to assume it's obvious to others they're the same. So I'll refrain from closevoting for now, to see if others vote that way (apparently *you* haven't, as yet! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The only thing that gave me pause was the introduction of "average" into the mix, which I think can obscure the 'specific thing' part of it.

Comment: @ColleenV:  I see your point. In the original, whether we talk about ***the*** or ***a** man on the Clapham omnibus* has no implications for whether there are ***other*** men on that same bus (which hardly matters, since that man is / those men are only hypothetical anyway. I think that just means *this* question is inherently a somewhat simpler "generic" version of an original that focuses on a *specific* context where the application of the general principle might not be quite so obvious.

Comment: Also just so you know Blaszard, a duplicate question isn't a bad question. The SO blog discusses how some duplicates are good to have around: [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Comment: @ColleenV, Blaszard: Absolutely! I would never vote to ***delete*** this question, and although I'm not 100% sure, I don't think having your question closed as a dup adversely affects your site reputation (I'd be *very* disappointed if it did). The more dups there are, the more obvious it is that this is an ***important*** question (plus it's easier to find at least one earlier question resolving your problem, if there are several of them already). *But*, I'm increasingly thinking this one ***is*** a dup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FF's comment provided the perfect answer:

> Your first version (with indefinite article a) implies Selfcompany is just one of many companies that make life better. Using the definite article the implies Selfcompany is the only one that does this. This difference arises from the "standard" principle that the references a specific thing known to both speaker and audience and/or previously mentioned in the current conversation. – FumbleFingers

However, as an editor I would suggest that you drop the use of "company" altogether, and instead simply write

> SelfCompany makes your life better by XXXing.

As you noted, your readers (or listeners) will already know that it is your company. Don't overthink it. (And best wishes on your new endeavor!)

Comment: What you and @FumbleFingers said, with one caveat: using _the_ in this particular context strikes me as a marketing ploy. In other words, the version with _the_ seems to say: "There may be other companies that _try_ to make your life better by XXXing, but no company does it nearly as well as we do; therefore, we'll be bold and use the definite article."

Comment: It is "Ace is *the* place...", not *a* place, after all @J.R.